# Search and remove from content?

Tags: php

I have this content "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,**[Hello world]** consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare luctus diam sit amet mollis." 
 I want to remove any thing wrap by `[]`
so the result of this content should be removed **[Hello world]**
Like this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare luctus diam sit amet mollis.

Comment: [`$output = preg_replace('#\[.+?\]#s', '', $input)`](http://us.php.net/preg_replace).

Comment: look up preg_replace http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,[Hello world] consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare luctus diam sit amet mollis.';
$newString = preg_replace('/\[.+?\]/', '', $string);
echo $newString;
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/QiJ12TFD)

Comment: Result is same from $string !!

Comment: Added Codepad Example .. it's not !!

Answer (score 0):

[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is the way to go. It uses a regular expression to match a pattern in your input string (third parameter) and returns a string that replaces anything that matches the pattern (first parameter) with your replacement string (second parameter).

```
$input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,[Hello world] consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare luctus diam sit amet mollis.";
$output = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/', '', $input);
echo $output;
```

Will give you:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare luctus diam sit amet mollis.
```

- An important thing to realize in this case is that you need to use a `\` to escape the `[` and `]` characters because they have special meaning in regular expressions. The Wikipedia entry on regular expressions has a section that goes over the [syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Syntax) and covers other metacharacters.
- Another consideration is that you should use `+` for nongreedy matching instead of `*` because if your input is:

  ```
  $input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,[Hello world] consectetur [test] adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare luctus diam sit amet mollis.";
  ```

  then your output will remove `consectetur` which you probably don't want and give you:

  ```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipiscing elit. Mauris ornare luctus diam sit amet mollis.
  ```